# Проблема с запуском Telegram бота на Python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Пытаюсь написать примитивного бота с использованием `pyTelegramBotAPI`, но при компиляции вылезает куча ошибок, и все сводятся к тому, что:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
```

Включение прокси не помогает. Вот сам код бота:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


bot.polling()
```

Далее прилагаю полный список ошибок.

```
2020-05-07 19:18:42,444 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1076870220:AAFN6PreEjh-rAL7qPVUjc-qH6uIsTh9WGA/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 308, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1076870220:AAFN6PreEjh-rAL7qPVUjc-qH6uIsTh9WGA/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 281, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 251, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 199, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 62, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1076870220:AAFN6PreEjh-rAL7qPVUjc-qH6uIsTh9WGA/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 308, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1076870220:AAFN6PreEjh-rAL7qPVUjc-qH6uIsTh9WGA/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents/py/telegrambot/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 438, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 81, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 281, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 251, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 199, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 62, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(method, request_url, params=params, files=files,
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Documents\py\telegrambot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1076870220:AAFN6PreEjh-rAL7qPVUjc-qH6uIsTh9WGA/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000000414A8B9700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Тут не прокси нужен, а VPN. Либо запускайте бота на зарубежном VPS

Comment: Спасибо, поставил VPN от TunnelBear, все заработало

Answer (score 2):

Согласно постоновлению номер № 02-1779/2018 Таганского суда г. Москвы от 14.06.2018 [cм](https://www.mos-gorsud.ru/rs/taganskij/services/cases/civil/details/2cc72aea-39e7-4f8e-adc9-37d170966efa) телеграм заблокирован на территории РФ. Подробнее в википедии [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_Telegram_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) Для того что бы пользоваться функционалом бота:

1) Запускать бота из за границы, т.е. либо физический пользоваться не российскими IP  либо воспользоваться сервисом для удаленного запуска питон скриптов (например pythonAnywhere).

2) Пользоваться прокси.
Для прокси используйте:

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://x.x.x.x:port'}
```

Где вместо Х укажите IP адрес и Порт. Прокси можно взять с любого открытого банка прокси в интернете, например [здесь](https://free-proxy-list.net/)

3) Пользоваться VPN. Например [этим](https://hidemy.name/ru/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Search_Competitors_RU&utm_content=hide.me&utm_term=%2Bhide%20%2Bme%20%2Bvpn&gclid=CjwKCAjw4871BRAjEiwAbxXi2_QzOibYpjpkB2wtOevup0OObVG8SBOt_Un6yoUq_eco8fCyfu0AchoCxHAQAvD_BwE#567140d38cf9f) или любым другим, по вашему усмотрению.

Answer (score 0):

18 июня, этого года, все ограничения и запреты на территории РФ, касательно месенджера Telegram сняты. Сейчас боты работают без всяких прокси и VPN.

В конце бота, вместо `bot.polling()` пропишите:

```py
while True:
    try:
      bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except:
      print('upalo')
      logging.error('error: {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
      time.sleep(5)
```

Но еще лучше, написать бота на PHP.

Comment: Чем это вдруг PHP будет лучше, чем Python?

Comment: У меня не удалось толком на питое завести бота так, чтобы он работал круглосуточно, без перебоев. Он постоянно падал. Написал на пыхе - работет с 27го июня, по сей день - ни разу не падал.

Comment: в чём проблема отследить причину падения и понаставить try/except?